# Cant save the user input to a variable

Tags: c, function, insert

Hello everyone I m doing my homework and i have some problem.

This are my variables:

```
struct student
{
    int facN;
    char name[MAX_LENGHT + 1];
    char prezime[MAX_LENGHT + 1];
    char familiq[MAX_LENGHT + 1];
    char specialnost[MAX_LENGHT + 1];
    int group;
    int kurs;
};
typedef struct student BODY;
```

And the function for the input is:

```
int enterBody(BODY *ps)
{
    if (ps == NULL) return 0;
    memset(ps, 0, sizeof(BODY));

    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nFaculty No: ");
    scanf("%d", &(ps->facN));
    //fflush(stdin);

    printf("\nName: ");
    gets(ps->name);

    printf("\nPrezime: ");
    gets(ps->prezime);

    printf("\nFamiliq: ");
    gets(ps->familiq);

    printf("\nSpecialnost: ");
    gets(ps->specialnost);

    printf("\ngrupa: ");
    gets(ps->group);

    printf("\kurs: ");
    gets(ps->kurs);

    return 1;
}
```

The main problem is when i run the program I cant get Prezime and the others after that to get on the the screen and after that to save the input into the varaibles.

Comment: 1. `fflush(stdin);` invokes undefined behaviour. 2. Never use `gets()`.

Comment: `gets` is obsolete, but that and `fgets` will read the `newline` left in the buffer after `scanf`. To avoid that, use `scanf("%d%*c", &ps->facN);` so `scanf` will read and throw away the `newline` following the numeric entry.

Answer (score 0):

1. `fflush(stdin);` invokes undefined behaviour, so you should remove these statements.
2. `memset()`ing the struct makes no sense, because it'll be filled with data in the end.
3. Use `scanf(" %d%*c", &var);`, rather than `gets()` to input `int` fields. `%*c` is added to discard a `'\n'` character.
4. `gets()` doesn't have buffer overflow protection, so call `fgets()` instead. Also, use `strcspn()` to remove the tailing `'\n'` written by `fgets()`.
5. I suppose you mean `printf("\nkurs: ");`.

Refined code:

```
int enterBody(BODY *ps)
{
    if (ps == NULL)
        return 0;

    printf("\nFaculty No: ");
    scanf(" %d%*c", &ps->facN);

    printf("\nName: ");
    fgets(ps->name, MAX_LENGHT + 1, stdin);
    (ps->name)[strcspn((ps->name), "\n")] = '\0';

    printf("\nPrezime: ");
    fgets(ps->prezume, MAX_LENGHT + 1, stdin);
    (ps->prezume)[strcspn((ps->prezume), "\n")] = '\0';

    printf("\nFamiliq: ");
    fgets(ps->familiq, MAX_LENGHT + 1, stdin);
    (ps->familiq)[strcspn((ps->familiq), "\n")] = '\0';

    printf("\nSpecialnost: ");
    fgets(ps->specialnost, MAX_LENGHT + 1, stdin);
    (ps->specialnost)[strcspn((ps->specialnost), "\n")] = '\0';

    printf("\ngrupa: ");
    scanf(" %d%*c", &ps->group);

    printf("\nkurs: ");
    scanf(" %d%*c", &ps->kurs);

    return 1;
}
```